# NAS TerraMaster F2-221 comandos limitados

Tags: linux, servidor

Buenas querría ayuda en un tema sobre mi servidor nas. Este servidor trae un SO basado en Linux llamado TOS con interfaz gráfica personalizada por la empresa q los vende.

Este SO tiene una tienda de app y muchas prestaciones. No está mal en ese sentido. Pero me gustaría tener la capacidad de poder editar e instalar lo q quisiera para todo esto pues necesito una terminal. 
Puede ser que yo no lo encontrara pero no veo ninguna app de terminal bash ni nada. La única forma que encontré es acceder al servidor desde otro pc con SSH.

Hasta aquí guay. Veo q puedo al menos tener la terminal si acceso desde ssh. Pero rápidamente veo el siguiente problema: no reconoce el comando sudo... No reconoce apt install... Etc etc .. es decir , mis intenciones de personalizar lo q yo quiera y como quiera no es posigle. No puedo instalar ninguna app si no es por la app store que tiene el SO.

Lo único así que puedo hacer es lanzar el comando MySQL para entrar en la BBDD. Pero vaya decepción. Se puede 'liberar' el servidor de alguna manera para hacer lo que yo quisiera?

De no ser así creo q devolvería el NAS y os haría esta otra pregunta:

Que alternativa a un NAS  puedo hacer para tener un servidor web y con sus BBDD en su server MySQL de la misma forma que está un nas (preparado para estar mucho tiempo encendido).

Comment: No sólo existe apt para instalar cosas, y si conoces la clave del user root del aparato, ya tienes todo el control. Puedes probar a usar uname -a para saber qué tipo de Linux tienes. Para tu segundo caso yo me decantaría por un proliant microserver. Instalas la distro que te parezca, consume pocos watt encendido 24h. También puedes mirar Raspberry Pi si no necesitas mucha potencia

Comment: Quieres que funcione como un Debian-based y no siempre vas a encontrar apt a la mano trabajando en Linux. Igual, yo sería muy cuidadoso con cambiar los repositorios para añadir otros paquetes, porque puede que haya optimizaciones o configuraciones específicas para el NAS que te pierdas y termines en un lío de dependencias. Además, si ya tienes el NAS montado, no podrías usarlo como LVM o algo así en otro equipo e instalar cualquier cosa?

Comment: @Jakala no puedo entrar con sudo su . No reconoce sudo

Comment: @Alfabravo dices haciendo un mount desde mi PC no? Tengo una pregunta sobre eso en SO sobre que no he podido montarlo. Me daba error relacionado con el problema de q no encontraba el directorio. No se porque si existía todo.

Comment: su root tampoco funciona? De nuevo, estás suponiendo que va a funcionar cono Debian o Ubuntu

Comment: Estás suponiendo que un sistema **basado en linux** es equivalente **a una distribución linux estándar**. Ni remotamente. Esos dispositivos llevan un conjunto de comandos instalado **que dificilmente podrás ampliar**. Forzarlos a que te dejen instalar cosas a tu antojo es todo un trabajo completo de *hacking* que puede durar años, e incluir ingeniería *hardware*. Olvidate de poder hacer lo que quieres.

Comment: @Trauma  Habia pensado dos cosas : 1. Comprarme una rasspberry pi e instalarle ubuntu server, ponerle un mount en un directorio al NAS. 
ó 2: Devolver el nas y 'jugar' con una raspberry pi 4 con todo un acceso total para mis requisitos: root, comandos apt disponibles y todo lo que un OS libre ofrece. 

En principio lo quiero para testing y por supuesto aprender, pero pronto lo quiero usar como servidor de produccion para alojar apps y tal entonces no me gustaria devolver lo que tengo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yo tengo también el terramaster F2-221 y puedes montar en el un servidor web sin problemas, vamos por puntos:

1. Respecto a la consola, si que es verdad que solo podemos obtenerla accediendo por ssh, pero has de tener en cuenta una cosa, si te logueas por ssh con el usuario "admin" que te da por defecto el NAS, osea el que usas para entrar a la interfaz web, que sepas que no es el que más privilegios tiene, para ello debes loguearte con el usuario "root" y la password que le hayas puesto al usuario "admin". Si es cierto que no contamos con comandos como apt-get, que en ocasiones se echan en falta, pero a continuación te daré un par de tips para tener tu servidor web según la tecnología.
2. Bien, actualmente en nuestro TNAS podemos desplegar aplicaciones con las siguientes tecnologías:

   - Node.js: Como sabrás en la tienda de aplicaciones podemos instalar nodejs, una vez instalado podemos hacer uso de todo lo que nos permite el comando NPM, y si estás haciendo una aplicación en este lenguaje, para tener tu servidor en marcha, te recomiendo PM2, lo obtenemos con el comando "npm i pm2" y nos servirá para dejar arrancada nuestra aplicación aunque cerremos el terminal, es una herramienta bastante profesional, te recomiendo echarle un vistazo.
   - Java: Para desplegar una aplicación java, imagino que también habrás visto Apache Tomcat en la tienda de aplicaciones, así que poco más que decir.
   - PHP: Para desplegar nuestra web en PHP, simplemente deberás ir al "Panel de Control", y en el apartado de "Servicios en Red" verás una opción de servidor web, en la que puedes activarlo, elegir el puerto, cambiar la carpeta del directorio raíz de la web, e incluso activar conexión SSL, lo que sería htttps.
3. Por último, si nada de esto te ha servido, te recomiendo DOCKER, gracias a dios nuestro NAS cuenta en la tienda de aplicaciones con docker, algo que otros NAS no tienen, esta herramienta lo que nos permite es instalar una aplicación dentro de un mini linux, te pongo un ejemplo para que me entiendas:

   - Yo ahora mismo estoy haciendo una web, y utilizaré de base de datos MongoDB, como sabrás la tienda de aplicaciones no dispone de MongoDB, pues es tan sencillo como ir a la de docker, descargarte el contenedor de MongoDB y encenderlo, automáticamente tendrás dentro de tu NAS un mini linux con mongodb instalado, y además podrás acceder a su interior con el comando "docker exec -it nombre_del_contenedor /bin/bash" por si te fuese necesario editar algún archivo del contenedor (y aquí si disponemos de apt-get para poder instalar cualquier cosa).

Espero haberte ayudado, un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, me has ayudado a entender el TNAS, disculpa por la trdanza he estado ocupado. Ahora ya tengo el ubuntu instalado pero me pregunto como acceder a el, con el comando que me pusistes me dice que no tengo permisos. Un saludo

Comment: @josanangel investiga sobre la imagen de docker que te has descargado, quizás la ruta correcta no sea /bin/bash